# Elimination of run time variation over repeated executions of the same program

Tags: performance, virtual-machine

I am trying to design an Online Programming Contest Judge, and one of the things that I need to ensure is that when the same code is compiled (assuming the requirement),
given the same input, it should take exactly the same amount of time for the program to execute, each time this is done.

Currently, I am using a simple python script that
has 2 threads, one of which invokes a blocking system call that starts the execution of the test code, and the other keeps track of time and sends a kill signal to the
child process after the time limit expires. Incidentally, I am doing this inside a virtual machine for reason of security, and convenience (setting up a proper chroot is
way too complicated, and more risky).

However, given identical conditions (ie, when I restore a snapshot), I still get a variation in the time taken for execution in range of approximately 50ms on either side. As this prevents setting strict time limits, is there anyway to eliminate this variation?

Comment: Why is it desirable or expected that you could get the code to take exactly the same amount of time to execute, to the millisecond? On a modern multithreaded OS, especially inside a virtual machine, the runtime must be expected to very by milliseconds at least.

Comment: There are many other things going on that affect scheduling, etc. Garbage collection is another variable. I/O adds even more randomness. Some variance in inevitable unless you are using a RTOS (and even then...). I would run the test code 50 times (for example), or more and average. Maybe check the variance to make sure nothing strange went on during the runs. My experience with this sort of thing comes from lisp, java & py based systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in that field, but I don't think you can do it. Even if you restore the snapshot inside the VM, the state of the "Outside" Machine is going to be pretty different. You have two OSs running, each one which multiple process which are probably going to compete for the resources at some point. If it's a website or a PC with an internet connection, you can get hit by different amounts of connections (or request), and that will make process start running and consume requests etc... If some application tries to access the hard disk, the initial position of the physical disk matters a lot for seek time, etc...

If you want a "deterministic" limit, you might wanna check if you can count how many instructions were executed by a certain process, or something like that.

Anyways, I've participated in several programming contents, and as far as I know, they don't care about the 50 ms differences... If you do a proper algorithm, you can get inside the time with a really big margin. So I'd advise you to live with it, and just include that in the rules.